# Shell: read a file and echo it's contents to another file

Tags: shell

I have a Makefile that is supposed to echo aliases from another file to your local `.zshrc` file.

I need to read the contents of the file `aliases.sh`, and echo it's contents to `~/.zshrc`, how is this possible?

Comment: Using the words "read" and "echo" here are somewhat suggesting a solution, and it's maybe not the best one -- there's no reason to copy the content into a shell variable (as read does) when the contents of the one file can simply be appended to the other without ever going through the shell.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
cat aliases.sh >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on permissions, I prefer the following:

```bash
$cat aliases.sh | sudo tee ~/.zshrc
```

If you dont want to overwrite the contents on the destination file use the `-a`.
This option tells tee to append to the given file instead of overwriting it.

```bash
$ cat aliases.sh | sudo tee -a ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question implying requirement for `sudo` and thus `tee`.  Actually the first line will (and the second one might) create a file with root-only permissions, possibly even unreadable for the current user (depending on `umask` value).